# Where should the virtual environment folder be kept within a django project?

Tags: django

I have a project directory that looks like this

- my_awesome_project (top level folder)

  - my_project_folder (generated by django)

    - my_project_folder
    - manage.py
    - .. other app folders
  - venv (virtual environment folder)

Is this good? I really don't know, and want to hear how other's deal with where their virtual environment folder exists.

I couldn't think of other ways to structure it.

Comment: Yes, it's okay like that. Its recomended to have a top level directory as you have where you save al the other directories. Nice job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is there is no answer. Put it wherever you like.

I do one of 2 things:

1. Have it in the project dir
2. Have a venv dir under my home somewhere and put them all there.

Both are fine, or elsewhere is also fine.

A couple of caveats:

- Do NOT share venvs between projects - this will lead to headaches when dependencies change.
- If you put your venv within the project dir, add it to your `.gitignore`, becuase you should not be committing it to the repo. There shoule be some form of requirements file which allows it to be rebuilt wherever the project is installed.

And finally - pin as many requirements as you can. Definitely top level dependencies for your project, and potentially all of them using something like pip tools/ pip compile.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the virtual envionment does not really matter. The environment can be sourced from any location within your terminal. You can look into environment management tools like poetry, pipenv, conda, hatch etc

Answer (score 0):

You should put the virtual environment in your project's root directory. Now your project's root directory is the one where your manage.py file in generated so your env folder should be where your manage.py file is.

Comment: Hello Faizan. I read that we need to install django in our venv before we actually create the project with django-admin startproject myapp. That's why my venv existed outside my project's root directory. What should i do so that the venv can be inside the project's root directory?

Comment: There's no reason to put the venv in the project root. The way in the question looks fine to me. You might want to share the same venv between two (or more) projects.

Comment: There's no "should" here. Having it in project root is fine. Having a directory under your home dir where you hold all your venvs is also fine, or putting it somewhere else, @nigel222 - I would _not_ share venvs between projects!!

Comment: @JunWenSoh after creating your project using django-admin, grab the venv directory and put it inside the project's root directory.